# How to use meteor iron:router to redirect from one page to another?

Tags: meteor

I have created one website in Meteor and i have created two html file default.html and home.html then how to redirect from default.html page to home.html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any special conditions to make it happen? Otherwise, as I could understand from your question, something like this would work:

```
Router.route('/default', function(){ 
    this.redirect('/home') 
}, {name: 'default'});
```

When `/default` is opened, it redirects to the `/home` URL. You can also add some conditions to it.

Comment: If i use this then it renders both html file on one browser page

Comment: But should it redirect to /home after something happens, or as soon user lands on page, should it render using `home` template? What do you want it to happen?

Comment: I understand that when i use this statement it renders from one template to another but is it possible to do like redirecting from one html page to another or it is possible with only rendering template?

Comment: See if it helps:

`Router.route('/default', function(){ this.redirect('/home') }, {name: 'default'});`

This run a function when on `/default` and this function redirects to homepage. Looks like you can even add some conditions to it.